# problem captcha when scraping a website using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, captcha, cloudflare

I want to scrape a website protected by `cloudflare`. However, when I get the returned data by a `NodeJS` library called "cloudscraper," this is what the terminal returns to me:

[image]

Is there any solution to bypass this message to get the full response of the webpage?